# Locus of a point from which three mutually perpendicular tangent lines can be drawn to paraboloid

Tags: conic-sections, tangent-line, locus

Show that locus of a point from which three mutually perpendicular tangent lines can be drawn to paraboloid $x^2+y^2+2z=0$ is $x^2+y^2+4z=1$.

Attempt: Assumed the point to be $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ and formed equation of 3 lines passing from $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ and with DR's $(l_1,m_1,n_1)$,$(l_2,m_2,n_2)$ and $(l_3,m_3,n_3)$
and as the lines are mutually perpendicular the properties $l_1l_2+m_1m_2+n_1n_2=0$ etc holds true.

But I cannot move further in the direction to solve the problem. Is the approach incorrect or needs to be followed with some changes? Any help appreciated

Comment: May I know the source of this question?

Comment: Found it in one of the examinations of mathematics for undergraduate level students.

Answer (score 2):

Question can be solved via Enveloping Cone concept:

1. Find enveloping cone via

   > S . S1 = T^2
2. Then use condition of 3 Mutually ⊥ Lines

   > a + b + c = 0

where, for Paraboloid `a x^2 + b y^2 = 2cz`

`S ≡ a x^2 + b y^2 - 2cz = 0`

Let Vertex i.e. Point from where 3 Mutually ⊥ Lines are drawn be `V (α, β, γ)`

`S1 = a α^2 + b β^2 - 2cγ`

`T = a αx + b βy - c(z + γ)`

`a = coefficient of x^2`

`b = coefficient of y^2`

`c = coefficient of z^2`

use this method and you'll get the desired result.

Comment: The concept which I have provided is a standard method given in Conicoids notebooks for higher studies. For details of this method you can refer to any book on Analytical Geometry - 3D. Link to Books: [3D Krishna Series](https://www.amazon.in/ME-Analytical-Geometry-3-Dimensions/dp/8182837979), [Analytical Solid Geometry - by Shanti Narayan](https://www.amazon.in/Analytical-Solid-Geometry-Narayan-Shanti/dp/8121926610)

Answer (score 1):

For any three prependicular line $l_1^2 + l_2^2 + l_3^2 =1$ , $m_1^2+m_2^2+m_3^2 =1$ and $n_1^2+n_1^2+n_1^2 =1 , l_1m_1 + l_2m_2+l_3m_3 = 0 $ and similarly for $\sum_{i=1}^3m_in_i = 0$ $\sum_{i=1}^3l_in_i = 0 $.

Now let line to be $\frac{x-\alpha}{l_1} = \frac{y-\beta}{m_1} = \frac{z-\gamma}{n_1}$
solve it with parabola and make root equal using $b^2-4ac= 0$ which will result into an equation like
$(l_1\alpha + m_1\beta + n_1\gamma)^2 = (\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + 2\gamma)(l_1^2+m_1^2)$

There will be two more similar equation in $l_2,m_2,n_2$ and $l_3,m_3,n_3$.
Add these three equations and use the above mentioned relations.
Hope it helps.